# Is there any NodeJs lib to verify Android V2 signature of apk files?

Tags: android, node.js

I need to verify Android V2 APK file using Node Js. 
There are few ways to do it using Java but couldn't find it for node js.  There is Java way : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/

Anyone has clue how to do it using NodeJs?